# Is sql caching my procedure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

Step 1 (Work)

//asp.net

```
public DataSet RepairList()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            openConnection();
            komut.CommandText = "RepairList";
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogClass MyLog = new LogClass();
            MyLog.LogInsert("", "221", ex.ToString(), "0");
        }
        finally
        {
            closeConnection();
        }

        return ds;
    }
```

//sql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RepairList]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Select Id, ProductId from Repairs Order By Id Desc
END

// result  
 1   3,
 2   4,
 4   9
```

Step 2(Not Work)
I alter my procedure, it works in sql but asp.net get different result

//asp.net

```
public DataSet RepairList()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            openConnection();
            komut.CommandText = "RepairList";
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogClass MyLog = new LogClass();
            MyLog.LogInsert("", "221", ex.ToString(), "0");
        }
        finally
        {
            closeConnection();
        }

        return ds;
    }
```

//sql

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RepairList]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Select Id, ProductId, ImageUrl from Repairs Order By Id Desc
END

//sql result 

         1   3   asdf.jpg,
         2   4   df.jpg,
         4   9   sfkas.jpg


//asp.net result(wrong)  

         1   3,
         2   4,
         4   9
```

Step 3 (Work) I create same procedure but different name(RepairList -> RepairsList) then results are same and correct

//asp.net

```
public DataSet RepairList()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            openConnection();
            komut.CommandText = "RepairsList";
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogClass MyLog = new LogClass();
            MyLog.LogInsert("", "221", ex.ToString(), "0");
        }
        finally
        {
            closeConnection();
        }

        return ds;
    }


//sql


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RepairsList]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Select Id, ProductId, ImageUrl from Repairs Order By Id Desc
END
//sql result 
         1   3   asdf.jpg,
         2   4   df.jpg,
         4   9   sfkas.jpg

//asp.net result 
         1   3   asdf.jpg,
         2   4   df.jpg,
         4   9   sfkas.jpg
```

What's my problem in step 2
thanks...

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but **not** a database product... Procedure caching is very much vendor-specific - so we really need to know database **product** you're using...

Comment: @marc_s makes a good point.  However, databases typically don't cache the **results** of a stored procedure, rather they cache the **compiled plan** to execute it.

Comment: Did you restart the application each time? Are you sure that you don't cache the dataset, for example? Are you sure the stored proc was actually called again until 3? It feels like you might be caching something in the application tier.

Comment: I use mssql 2008 10.50.1600, I clean cache(syscacheobjects), also I delete my procedure but asp.net result didn't changed..I restart my application but asp.net result didn't changed..Also If I use my local sql(mssql 2008 10.0.5500) asp.net results are correct; but when I changed web.config to live db I get this error :S